# User Registration login in profile page

Tags: profile, registration, user

I just want to move the user registration login page to contribution page , before the payment processor. Can anyone say how to do tat? i have attached my screenshot below.
[image]

[image]

---

i'm not using event registration.. [image]

I'm using customise Data screen-> profile

Comment: Do you want to change the display order or do you want to create a new page - please clarify

Comment: i want to change the order

Comment: Please send me the link which you are trying saying (like : http://<example>/civicrm/contribute/transact?reset=1&id=2) from /civicrm... so i can tell you the exact file

Comment: I'm using localhost you can't open it...

Comment: You know contribution page na? In tat page i want to add user registertion page (only username,password, and confirm password) above the payment processor of contribution page...

Comment: I just wanted you to make sure you are using the same page /civicrm/contribute/transact - I wasn't trying to access your page

Comment: John - if I understand the above, you have a Contribution page that has 'account creation' enabled already. And the problem is that you are missing the ability to allow the 'user' to set their password and hence be logged in. Is that the nub of this problem? In Drupal we have worked around this by the use of Rules (at least from a Webform page) so it could potentially work from a Contribution page, ie they get an account created and get logged in automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure whether this correct way – But easy way – I did once for Event registration

Just make sure you have the same file path on your address bar (highlighted one)
http://examplesite**/civicrm/contribute/transact**

If yes then you will find a file called main.tpl in the below location 
**civicrm\templates\CRM\Contribute\Form\Contribution\Main.tpl**

Where you can change the order by just playing around in it – also please use custom tpl folder and copy the file over there

Comment: The example i have given is for contribution and not for Event - Please look into the file for custom block and change the order - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding, I think you can just move the profile that has the account creation option to the top of the page in the Profiles tab of the Contribution Page itself (rather than changing a setting within the Profile you created):

[image: Contribution page > Profile tab]